# Want to open two separate windows

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have 20 links and I want to open first 10 in a separate window and the remaining in a separate second window. 
Issue is my all links are being opened in 20 tabs in a single window.Wrote following Javascript code.

```
  function myFunction() {
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/first.aspx', '1');
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/second.aspx', '2');
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/third.aspx', '3');
    ......
    ......
    ......
   window.open('http://localhost/sample/twenty.aspx', '20');
  }
```

then I tried this

```
  function myFunction() {
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/first.aspx', '1');
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/second.aspx', '2');
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/third.aspx', '3');
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/eleventh.aspx', 'myWindow', "height=200,width=200",'1');
    window.open('http://localhost/sample/twelfth.aspx', 'myWindow', "height=200,width=200",'2');
 }
```

though this opens a new window but it over rides all the links and shows only one link(whichever is the last) opened.

Means,if we take this code as an example as it is written here,  first 3 links open properly in 3 tabs in a single window,after that a window opens with having only 'localhost/sample/twelfth.aspx' opened in that new window.

what to do to resolve this issue and open specific number of links in separate tabs in a separate window?

Comment: @Jamiec actuallly its a kind of requirement, so in that particular case we actually do :)

Comment: You're going to have one very unhappy client/BA then :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this isn't something that's controllable through javascript itself since this affects browser behavior. 
Looking through most browsers there's settings for how to treat links, especially new tab vs. new window.

So, without knowing with 100% certainty, I'd say no, it's not possible to do with just plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To open link in new window

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings')
```

To open link in new tab

```
window.open('_link is here_', 'name');
```

Where '**name**' :-

**_blank** - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default

**_parent** - URL is loaded into the parent frame

**_self** - URL replaces the current page

**_top** - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

you can use this.

Comment: If I add '_parent' which is the most related term among all of the others, link will be opened in first window as It is the parent it opens up first.

Comment: In _parent that window will open in a new tab with focus on that tab only

Comment: but my requirement specifically is opening 10 tabs only in each window.

Comment: It would get opened 10 tabs in single window and also a new window gets opened but for rest of 9 tab which you want to open in new tab, I don't think it is possible. Because how browser knows for the new parent window's object is get or not.

Comment: exactly this is the problem that I am looking the solution for.